# Is it possible to capture both mic and line-in at the same time using ALSA?

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

Not terribly familiar with ALSA, but I'm supporting an application that uses it.

Is it possible to record audio from both the mic and line-in simultaneously? Not necessarily mixing the audio, though that is a possibility that has been requested. Can both be set to record and use ALSA to read each individually?

Documentation on ALSA is not terribly helpful, and this is basically my first sojourn into sound mixing on Linux using ALSA.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated; hoping there is someone out there that has done something like this in the past and either has a sample to share or a link to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arecord -l` will give you a list of available capture devices. In my case:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: M2496 [M Audio Audiophile 24/96], device 0: ICE1712 multi [ICE1712 multi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So, with my card, you would be out of luck - there is only one device (i.e. only one distinct source). This device will give you all data routed to it by hardware, as configured by an external mixer application.

With some cards it **might**, however, be possible to route MIC to channel 1 (left) and LINE to channels 2 (right), and then record 2 channels, separating them as needed in your application. Of course, if supported by hardware, you could also use two channels each and record four channels.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm working on an embedded system, and the only capture device that shows is the built-in audio mixer. It has controls for both line and mic input, but apparently I have no way to join them; board appears to be hard-wired/limited to only one input channel at a time. I did find a way to tell the line in to bypass the codec and play directly to the speaker, so that may be what I wind up doing in the long run.
Problem still persists, however, that there is no C code explaining how to do this; I'm still having to system() a call to amixer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be done: Not sure, but from http://www.jrigg.co.uk/linuxaudio/ice1712multi.html ,not tested, but this will give you 1 virtual device with 4 channels.

```
pcm.multi_capture {  
    type multi  
    slaves.a.pcm hw:0  
    slaves.a.channels 2  
    slaves.b.pcm hw:1  
    slaves.b.channels 2  
    bindings.0.slave a  
    bindings.0.channel 0  
    bindings.1.slave a  
    bindings.1.channel 1  
    bindings.2.slave b  
    bindings.2.channel 0  
    bindings.3.slave b  
    bindings.3.channel 1  
}
```

I dont know if you can mix them with route or the correct sintax:

```
pcm.route_capture {  
 type route  
 slave.pcm "multi_capture"  
 ttable.0.0 0.5  
 ttable.1.1 0.5  
 ttable.0.2 0.5  
 ttable.1.3 0.5  
}
```

or

```
pcm.route_capture {  
 type route  
 slave.pcm "multi_capture"  
 ttable.0.0 0.5  
 ttable.1.1 0.5  
 ttable.2.0 0.5  
 ttable.3.1 0.5  
}
```

If someone test, please tells us the results? Thank you!
I wish you luck!